# How to connect to an API that requires a username and password with Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, api, angular, endpoint

Was wondering if anyone can guide me in the right direction. I have an endpoint that requires a username and password. I know how to create a service utilizing Angular 2 but not sure how to pass the credentials along. Any help and or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your api is using basic authentication you can pass Authorization header to the request as below.

```
      let username : string = 'myuser';
      let password : string = 'mypass';
      let headers = new Headers();
      headers.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
      headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
      return this._http.get(url,  {headers: headers}).map(data=>{})
```